# how do i convert a string with multiple types in c#

Tags: c#

I am getting a cast error for the `Url` value. Does anyone know how to cast a value to a string that contains multiple value types?

```
CmdRecipients = new OleDbCommand(QueryRecipients, ConnRecipients);
Recipients = CmdRecipients.ExecuteReader();

while (Recipients.Read())
{
    Url = "https://bulktext.vodafone.ie/sendmessage.aspx"
          + "?user=user&password=user1!&api_id=89&to="
          + Recipients.GetString(8)
          + "&text=" + Confirmations.GetString(4)
          + "%0d%0a" + Confirmations.GetString(5)
          + "%0d%0a" + Confirmations.GetString(6)
          + "&from=Service";

    Console.Write("Sending text to " + Recipients.GetString(8) + " ... ");

    //Send SMS Here
    HttpWebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(Url) as HttpWebRequest;
    string result = null;
    using (HttpWebResponse resp = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
    {
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
        result = reader.ReadToEnd();
        if (result == "0\nRequest deferred successfully")
        {
            QueryRecipients = "UPDATE [Test].[dbo].[MessagesToSend] SET Previous_Status = Current_Status,"
                              + "Current_Status = \"Sent\", DateTime_sent = Now() "
                              + "WHERE Task_ID = \"" + Recipients.GetString(2) + "\";";

            OleDbCommand Update = new OleDbCommand(QueryRecipients, ConnConfirmations);
            Update.ExecuteNonQuery();

            Console.WriteLine("Done!");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The text wasn't delivered properly.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "*a string with multiple types*" - not entirely sure what you mean by that. What type is `Url`? If it's not a `string` then you can't assign a `string` value to it like you are trying to do in your code. Also, the error itself could be quite useful if you posted it...

Comment: SQL injection warning!

Comment: You're calling `SqlDataReader.GetString(int i)` on `Recipients` and `Confirmations` - are the fields you're trying to get the values of actually strings?
If they're not, then `InvalidCastException` will be raised.

Comment: `Url` is going to be either a string or a `System.Uri` due to its later use in `WebRequest.Create(Url)` - please edit the original post to show the declaration of the `Url` variable to give more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a bit vague as you're not telling us where the exception is thrown, nor what the exception is exactly.

I would suspect that the problem lies in your use of `Confirmations.GetString(x)` and `Recipients.GetString(x)`. As I understand, these are results from database calls. If the respective fields returned by the select don't contain strings, the `GetString` call will fail. You need to use the method that matches the field's type, like `GetBoolean`, `GetInt32`,  etc.